# Django dynamic URL pattern returns 404

Tags: python, django, url, design-patterns, http-status-code-404

I'm currently building a Django CMS App.

When I try to use dynamic url patterns, I get only 404.

Debug = True

returns:

> Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> [...]
>
> ro/ gallery/int:folder_pk/ [name='dynamic_gallery_view']
>
> [...]
>
> The current path, /ro/gallery/3/, didn’t match any of these.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (postBarbersCards_create_employee,
                    postBarbersCards_create_location,
                    postBarbersCards_update_employee,
                    postBarbersCards_update_location,
                    postBarbersCards_delete_employee,
                    postBarbersCards_delete_location,
                    postBarbersCards_caroussel,
                    render_gallery_location,
                    render_gallery_location_selector)



urlpatterns = [
    # ... other urls
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_create_employee', postBarbersCards_create_employee, name = "postBarbersCards_create_employee"),
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_create_location', postBarbersCards_create_location, name = "postBarbersCards_create_location"),
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_update_employee', postBarbersCards_update_employee, name = "postBarbersCards_update_employee"),
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_update_location', postBarbersCards_update_location, name = "postBarbersCards_update_location"),
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_delete_employee', postBarbersCards_delete_employee, name = "postBarbersCards_delete_employee"),
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_delete_location', postBarbersCards_delete_location, name = "postBarbersCards_delete_location"),
    path('post/ajax/postBarbersCards_caroussel', postBarbersCards_caroussel, name = "postBarbersCards_caroussel"),
    path('gallery/<int:folder_pk>/',render_gallery_location, name='dynamic_gallery_view'),
    path('gallery/location',render_gallery_location_selector, name='dynamic_gallery_location_view'),

    # ...
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Barbers_Locations_Model, Barbers_Employees_Model
from filer.models.filemodels import File
from filer.models.foldermodels import Folder
import json

[...]

def render_gallery_location(request, folder_pk):
    item = File.objects.filter(folder_id=folder_pk).values('file', 'folder_id')
    return render(request, '_barbers_cards_gallery_page.html', {'item': item })
```

I tested everything beforehand on my DEV server and it worked with the build in Django webserver.
Now, when I try to go into production, it seems broken.

What do I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

was worried about the spaces after ro/ too, but the other url patterns show the same and work just fine.

debug url patterns:

```
@dcf-links/
ro/ jsi18n/ [name='javascript-catalog']
ro/ admin/
ro/ filer/
ro/ ^cms_login/$ [name='cms_login']
ro/ ^cms_wizard/
ro/ ^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$ [name='pages-details-by-slug']
ro/ ^$ [name='pages-root']
ro/ ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_create_employee [name='postBarbersCards_create_employee']
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_create_location [name='postBarbersCards_create_location']
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_update_employee [name='postBarbersCards_update_employee']
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_update_location [name='postBarbersCards_update_location']
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_delete_employee [name='postBarbersCards_delete_employee']
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_delete_location [name='postBarbersCards_delete_location']
ro/ post/ajax/postBarbersCards_caroussel [name='postBarbersCards_caroussel']
ro/ gallery/<int:folder_pk>/ [name='dynamic_gallery_view']
ro/ gallery/location [name='dynamic_gallery_location_view']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

root urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import path, include,re_path

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('filer/', include('filer.urls')),
    path('', include('cms.urls')),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',serve,{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    path('',include('Apps.barbers_cards.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

indeed i checked on my dev-server and saw, that the same app calles this url without the language tag, but can't find the difference in any urls.py.

Comment: Can you show your root `urls.py`? In your URL you have `/ro/gallery/3/`, but where is the `ro` mapped? My guess is that somewhere in your root `urls.py` you have made a mistake

Comment: The space in `ro/ gallery/int:fold...` may be a mistake and could be a hint.

Comment: added the requested info in UPDATE. thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

after your input and checking the root urls.py + the finding that the dev server does not have the language tag included for these pages, I came up with the following solution:

I modified the root urls.py, so that my custom pages do not require localization. I splitted the i18n_patterns from non-i18n_patterns

```
urlpatterns = [path('',include('Apps.barbers_cards.urls'))]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('filer/', include('filer.urls')),
    path('', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

would be still nice to know, how it can work with localization for custom dynamic pages too.